# Writing 'if' statements a after a test passes or fails in mocha-chai in node js

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

Is there a way I could write an 'if' statement after a test has passed or failed?

```
var assert = require('chai').assert;
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var first = require('../first');
describe('First', function(){ 
  it('first should return hello world', function(){ 
    assert.equal(first(), 'hello world') 
  });
});
```

Comment: To help you, we will need to have at least a part of your code (where the problem occurs). Please also add an example of what you expect as output; that can be helpful !

Comment: Here is the code....

*var assert = require('chai').assert;
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var first = require('../first');

describe('First', function(){
    it('first should return hello world', function(){
        assert.equal(first(), 'hello world')
    });
});*

What i want to know is, if the test fails or pass, how can i continue to tell the app to do something. 

for example, if the test passes, i want to console log to call an api on testrail to modify a test run and set it to pass. if it fails, i want to create a ticket with jira using api. I have all the APIs

Answer (score 1):

### Yes, you can

Check out [Mocha - before, after, before each, after each hooks](https://mochajs.org/#hooks)

In you code it would be something like:

```
describe('First', function(){ 

  afterEach(function() {
     // runs after each test in this block
  });

  after(function() {
     // runs after all tests in this block
  });

  it('first should return hello world', function(){ 
    assert.equal(first(), 'hello world') 

    // if you want another assertion you can add one here. for example:
    assert.notEqual(first(), 'bye world') 
  });
});
```